# Pandas - Identify % of unique entries per column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe. I would like to find out, for each column, how many unique entries I have with respect to the total size of the dataframe (a percentage).

In other words, I want to get a sense of how much "entropy" I have per column.

I thought the following would do it:

```
my_f = lambda x: x.unique()/len(x)
df.apply(my_fl)
```

but I get:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (35,), indices imply (35, 125)
```

Doesn't `apply` call my lambda function, once for each column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
my_f = lambda x: 1.0*len(x.unique())/len(x)
```

Plain `x.unique()` will be an array of the unique elements. Thus `x.unique()/len(x)` will be multiplying all of those elements, element-wise, by `1.0/len(x)`, and giving you back variably-lenghted arrays depending on the amount of unique entries per group.

Note that `len(x)` produces an integer, whereas `x.unique()` produces an *array* and the elements of that array will have whatever types they happened to have as entries in `x`. So it won't necessarily be the case that `x.unique()/len(x)` is well-defined at all. And even if it is technically defined, it might give you unexpected output.

For example, if one of the entries of `x` is the integer `4` and if `len(x)` is the integer `5`, then the entry in the output of the expression `x.unique()/len(x)` corresponding to the unique value `4` will actually be `0` (!) due to the specifics of integer division in Python.

Thus, even after correcting the mistake of computing the unique array instead of the length of the unique array, you must still be careful: `len(x.unique())/len(x)` will also result in an integer being divided by another integer, and most of the time the numerator will be less than the denominator, yielding `0`.

Consider the following toy example:

```
In [264]: dfrm
Out[264]: 
          A         B         C  D  E
0 -0.505698 -0.871505 -0.463435  a  a
1  0.879227 -1.010891 -0.007801  b  a
2  1.119962  0.252159 -1.189837  c  a
3 -0.172311 -0.403126  0.270885  d  a
4  1.395133  0.453722  0.232463  e  a
5  0.521169  1.293135 -0.877195  f  b
6  1.344043  0.066453 -1.015383  g  b
7 -0.952602  1.530535 -0.832182  h  b
8  0.557599  1.280014  0.329418  i  b
9 -2.699605  0.934329  0.466991  j  b

In [265]: dfrm.A.unique()
Out[265]: 
array([-0.50569806,  0.87922668,  1.11996225, -0.17231083,  1.39513253,
        0.52116909,  1.34404271, -0.95260174,  0.55759942, -2.69960545])

In [266]: dfrm.A.unique()/len(dfrm.A)
Out[266]: 
array([-0.05056981,  0.08792267,  0.11199622, -0.01723108,  0.13951325,
        0.05211691,  0.13440427, -0.09526017,  0.05575994, -0.26996054])

In [267]: dfrm.E.unique()/len(dfrm.E)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-267-96b4a1138673> in <module>()
----> 1 dfrm.E.unique()/len(dfrm.E)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

In [268]: len(dfrm.A.unique())/len(dfrm.A)
Out[268]: 1

In [269]: len(dfrm.E.unique())/len(dfrm.E)
Out[269]: 0

In [270]: 

In [270]: 1.0*len(dfrm.E.unique())/len(dfrm.E)
Out[270]: 0.2
```

Comment: Minor: you can use `x.nunique()` instead of `len(x.unique())`.